Remove encryption setting
How to remove the encryption setting on my Motorola G play smart phone?
I have had a friend try to help but he doesn't understand it. Also I don't know how it was set in the first place so I can't remove it without help

Do you have the encryption password?

What "encryption setting" are you talking about? There are three different "Motorola G play" versions, the oldest is from 2021 and comes with Android 10, thus it is encrypted by default and will always be encrypted as long as you don't root and mod the device.
